# Cannot start xv6 in qemu

Tags: operating-system, qemu, xv6

I use Debian Wheezy and I want to run a xv6 in qemu.
I have installed libsdl1.2-dev and then start run make qemu. But an error occured: Could not initalize SDL（could not find the device) exiting.

Answer (score 0):

It is because qemu is trying to start X by default.
Build it by using

`make qemu-nox`

or if you are SSHing to a remote machine, use `ssh -X`

Source: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mwalfish/classes/f10-cs395t/labs/lab1.html